# ASP.NET Core Ajax returns null

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-core

```
function addTeam() {
    var teamName = $("teamField").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'AddTeam',
        contentType: "application/json;",
        data:
            { team: "HELLO PLEASE WORK" },
        success: function () {
            alert("URA");
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert(error);
        }
    });
};

[HttpPost]
        public JsonResult AddTeam(string team)
        {
            teamRepository.Add(new Team { IsDelete = false, Name = team });
            teamRepository.SaveChanges(); 
            return Json(team);
        }
```

string team awlays returns null. i dont know whats the problem.
Searched for same issue in stackoverflow, but no one works for me

Comment: Try removing `contentType: "application/json;"`. I see no particular reason to send as JSON, since it's a simple string.

Comment: @ADyson lol it works. thank you

Comment: you can use ``contentType: "application/json;"``, but change Data to  `JSON.stringify({ team: "HELLO PLEASE WORK" })` and use ``[FromBody]`` for the action `AddTeam`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are sending in an object with the property "team", instead of just a raw string.

You can create a request object as your parameter:

```
public class AddTeamRequest
{
    public string Team {get; set;}
}
```

And then use that as your parameter object:

```
public JsonResult AddTeam(AddTeamRequest request)
```

Comment: it would work I guess, but there's no reason to overcomplicate things just to send one string!

Answer (score 0):

You cant get value because you cant get it from html.You should get team name like this. Just add #.

```
 function addTeam() {
    var teamName = $("#teamField").val();///this line
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'AddTeam',
        contentType: "application/json;",
        data:
            { team: "HELLO PLEASE WORK" },
        success: function () {
            alert("URA");
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert(error);
        }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You use `application/json`,so you put the data into body,if you want to get the data in post method,you can use `[FromBody]`.And the data you pass need to use `JSON.stringify(xxx)` to change the data type before `ajax`.
Here is a demo worked:

View:

```
var team1 = "HELLO PLEASE WORK";
        var team = JSON.stringify(team1) ;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'AddTeam',
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            data: team,
            success: function () {
                alert("URA");
            },
            error: function (error) {
                alert(error);
            }
        });
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
        public JsonResult AddTeam([FromBody]string team)
        {
            
            return Json(team);
        }
```

result:
[image]

Or you can use `contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",`,so that you don't need to use `[FromBody]` and don't need to change the data type.